# Jquery tools slideshow - changing effect on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools, window-resize

I'm using this plugin for slideshow: http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/slideshow.html

I want to change slideshow effect on window resize. My code: http://jsfiddle.net/genesiss/5L2CN/5/

```
var initSlideshow = function() {

    var effect = 'fade';
    if ($(window).width() < 300) {
        effect = 'default';
    }

    $(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div", {

    effect: effect,
    fadeOutSpeed: "slow",

    rotate: true

  }).slideshow({interval: 100});
};


$(function() {
  initSlideshow();
  $(".slidetabs").data('slideshow').play();

   $(window).resize(function () {
        $(".slidetabs").data('slideshow').stop();
        $(".slidetabs").tabs('destroy');
        initSlideshow();
        $(".slidetabs").data('slideshow').play();
    });


});
```

It seems that slideshow effect is always the same - one that is set at first initialization. You can see that by resizing 'Result' window in jsfiddle and noticing that it still has 'fade' efect (two slides on the screen at the same time, one fading away).

How could I change slideshow effect after first initialization?

Comment: Your question is not clear... What different do effect do you want?

Comment: If you look at the code, I want to set the effect to 'default' instead of 'fade' if window.width is less than 300px.

Comment: An advice: avoid using such poorly documented plugins ! Always use jquery plugins that provide a variety of demos and code snippets and whose help is readily available !